# Application store problem

Tags: skype

I have recently installed ubuntu, so I am kind of trying to improve on my existing knowledge; I know Application store is supposedly the central hub for downloading applications but there is a problem with it (or with me)

I searched for Skype there and it returned no results, therefore I went to their official website and got the Ubuntu version. Even after it is installed I still cannot get skype in the list of "Already installed" software, I tried "Independent", "Canonical" and also "Provided by Ubuntu" still 0 results.

Let's assume I want to uninstall skype (or any other app), what should I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: But does it appear in the dash when you search skype? It should be in "Unknown" category in the Software Center at Already installed.

Comment: There is no unknown section, skype is literally nonexistent in every single category of the app store

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall Skype

`sudo apt-get remove skype:i386`

in fact you should be able to uninstall any app installed from **.deb** using **apt-get**

Comment: I am kind of a newbie to ubuntu so is this the thing I am supposed to write in the "run command" box when I press alt-F2?
 I understand the first part is some sort of command but, but how did you find out skype would be i386?

Comment: Open terminal by pressing **Ctrl+Alt+T** and enter the following commands

Comment: I got that ;) But what database did you check up on to know the app name? In this case skype:i386?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use terminal, I suggest you use synaptic instead of Ubuntu Software Center. It would list skype, google chrome, and all other softwares installed from deb files. Ofcourse you need to install it first. You can install it from Ubuntu Software Center. Just search for `Synaptic` from there.

Comment: I'll give it a try ;)